# Win32 development. Standards

Tags: c, windows, database, winapi, standards

A call to all Win32 developers... I'm developing an application in C using plain Win32. I wanted to ask about Windows development standards regarding these things:

- Is there a standard Windows error log api? For example if my client uses my app and it crashes, I would like them to send me the error log and I would prefer this being a standard location so they can maybe access it with a standard Windows log utility.
- My app needs to store settings information. I think the registry is the standard utility for this task. Is that right?
- My app needs to store and retrieve files that it downloaded from the internet - images, executables etc. Is `Application Data/myapp` the standard location to store this type of information?
- My app needs a very straight-forward database - I'm using CSV for this. I basically need to store and retrieve this type of data so I'm just serializing a .csv file from `Application Data/myapp`. Is there a better Windows standard way of doing this?

That's all for now :). Thanks!

Comment: don't hardcode the paths - use http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb762181%28v=vs.85%29.aspx instead, which respects localization...

Comment: Yes, I'm not hardcoding them... it was just a way of saying that I'm using that path.

Comment: This question is way too broad. I vote to close on that score. You need to ask these questions one at a time.

Comment: @David - who cares, just answer if you have one of the answers or ignore it if you don't. All the questions have a single subject in common - standard storage configuration for Windows apps - so I don't think it's that bad having them all in one place.

Comment: @Luca That's not how it works here, as far as I understand. As for your questions, I'd think you'd likely want to distinguish between storage for the app and per-user storage in the user's profile. Settings in the registry is standard enough, but I imagine you are proficient with text files so why not do it that way. Store user settings in the user profile, and app settings in what you call `Application Data`. There's lots of stuff on MSDN about this.

Comment: @David Heffernan: I don't see anything wrong with the question.  Yes, it could have been asked as four separate questions, but whether it should have been is entirely subjective.  I wouldn't vote to close on that score.

Comment: @JeremyP That's fine, we can all have our own views quite happily. I do feel that there may be some answers by now if the questions had been asked separately and with more focus.  By the way, I just gave you your 10k up-vote - congrats!!

Comment: @David: thank you.  Yes, you're probably right that some of the questions would have answers by now if asked separately.  @Luca:  you may want to consider David's comment seriously.

Comment: @Luca - If someone posts an answer to the first one, and another posts to the next two, which one will you accept as the correct one?

Comment: @Sertac, who cares... the idea is to provide answers. both of them will get an upvote. The correct one will be something that provides all answers. Why are you guys being so anal about this?

Comment: @Luca - Well, because then status of some answers might be misleading. By definition, the accepted answer is the one which helped you most to solve your problem. In the case of multiple questions though, this might not be the actual case since you can accept only one answer. But as long as you believe you'll get an answer that will provide all answers I'm fine with that..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is there a standard Windows error log api?

There is the Windows Event Log, but I don't think you want a typical user having to go into it to extract your logged information.

You probably don't want to log by default, unless you're shipping questionable pre-release code.  When a user is experiencing problems, then you have them turn logging on.  In this case, I recommend placing the file somewhere that typical users have experience with, like My Documents.

By the way, if you're writing a standalone application and want the best possible information in the event of a crash, look into minidumps.  [Here is a Codeproject sample](http://www.codeproject.com/kb/debug/postmortemdebug_standalone1.aspx).

> My app needs to store settings information

Yep, registry.

> My app needs to store and retrieve files

Yes, App Data.  Just be sure to use SHGetFolderPath and CSIDL_APPDATA.

> My app needs a very straight-forward database

There's nothing wrong with CSV for simple data.  You could store the data in XML and use MSXML to process it, if you prefer.  I've used SQlite in the past when I needed fast, lightweight storage of more complicated data.

Comment: This is great information. Thanks very much Jeff. +30 if possible.